# Can code be executed by loading it into an img element?

Tags: javascript, html, security

I've read that images that come from the user should be sanitized. In order to understand how to prevent an exploit, I need to understand how the danger is manifested. Would the browser allow code to execute in an img element if it's loaded with code instead of an image? Or is there some other scenario to protect against? Thanks.

Comment: [IMG tag vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36447/img-tag-vulnerability)

Comment: Thanks, I'll read that. I'm primarily thinking of an uploaded image rather than a linked-to image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, code inside an image will be executed by the browser:

http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/squirrel/

If we view the source of this file, we see that there is valid html embedded in the valid binary code of the image. The browser will see this and say "Hey! I know what to do with that!" and just render it. It's not hard to imagine putting js inside `<script>` tags inside an image that will do all sorts of nasty things to your users.

Comment: And they say Windows is not secure. Why in the world would browsers execute code in an image? Did the browser designers not understand the concept of types?

Comment: To allow the greatest expandability and compatibility, browsers will forgive a lot of poor formatting and gracefully handle things it doesn't understand. This is what has made the web work so well and become so ubiquitous, requiring minimal effort on the part of any one participant. It also allows things like code executing from inside a picture...

Comment: The web could have become ubiquitous without dubious design choices. Imagine the potential harm if there's no sanitation and all the (billions?) of lines of redundant code required if there is. All instead of simply restricting the capability in a dozen or so browsers.